# How would I make this IF statement check for the value of val

Tags: jquery

I am working on a .js web development file and with a radio selection of 0,1,2 I want to check the following >0 of the returned value:

I have tried this for the first line: if (!$("input[name=bbClassification]:checked").val() > 0) {

```
if (!$("input[name=bbClassification]:checked").val()) {
    $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
    validationError = true;
} else {
    $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
}
```

I only want the code to run if the returned val > 0

Comment: @Barmar Barmar thank you for the help. When I add that logic, it works but does not update when other option is selected.

    if (!$("input[name=bbClassification]:checked").val() != "1") {
        $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
        $("input[name=bbMaterial]").closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
        validationError = true;
    } else {
        $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
        $("input[name=bbMaterial]").closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` returns a string. A non-empty string is always truthy, the numeric contents of the string is irrelevant.

Use a string comparison.

```
if ($("input[name=bbClassification]:checked").val() != "0") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below -

```
if (!$("input[name=bbClassification]:checked")) {
    $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
    validationError = true;
} else {
    $("input[name=bbClassification]").closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
}
```